# How to use a Property which depends the value of another property?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

There is a Custom Property which depends on the value of other System Property to be initialized properly in WinForms.

Let me give you an example. Let's create a class `WhateverButton: Button` with a Custom Property called `MyExampleProperty` and system Control Property let's use `this.Height`, which came from the Size of the Control.

```
public class WhateverButton : Button
{
   // member
   private int m_myExampleProperty;

   // constructor
   public WhateverButton() {
      m_myExampleProperty = 1;
   }
    
    // Property
    public int MyExampleProperty
    {
      get => m_myExampleProperty;
      set
      {
        m_myExampleProperty= value > (this.Height / 2F) ? 1 : value;
      }
    }

    // Every time the Size change, update the property
    protected override void OnSizeChanged (EventArgs e)
    {
      base.OnSizeChanged (e);

      m_myExampleProperty  = m_myExampleProperty > this.Height / 2F ? 1: m_myExampleProperty;

    }

}
```

Add the `WhateverButton` in the Form (with a size greater than default). WinForms generates the element (button, label, textbox and etc) by alphabetical order such as:

```
      this.buttonWhatever.Location = new System.Drawing.Point (413, 57); // L
      this.buttonWhatever.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding (3, 4, 3, 4); // M
      this.buttonWhatever.MyExampleProperty= 30; // M
      ... // Others Properties
      this.buttonWhatever.Name = "myElement"; // N
      this.buttonWhatever.Size = new System.Drawing.Size (50, 80); // S
      this.buttonWhatever.Text = "My Element"; // T
```

After changing the Property `MyExampleProperty` value by Form UI, it seems it works, but after saving the form (Ctrl+S) the property returns to 1.

`Debugging` is possible to figure it out that every time the Form is saved all the elements are created again by that order. When the time of the `MyExampleProperty` arrives the `Size` property is not created yet, which will assume the default `Height` and `Width` and of course, the value of the property will be wrong. If I just *rename* the `MyExampleProperty` to any other name that will be placed after the `Size` property in this example, it will work. Maybe I am missing something that I have no idea to search.

Comment: That's quite a weird property to have, you see... If I set it to something, and then try to `Console.WriteLine` it, I might not get the value I just set it. Is it a requirement to have it this way? Because it would better to separate it into two properties, one regular property that you can get and set, and another get-only property that uses the height to calculate its value.

Comment: Yes, it is. My dependency is the Size property.

Comment: I'm not asking whether the "dependency on the Size property" is a requirement. I'm asking whether "setting a value and then not getting that same value" is a requirement. You can still have a property that depends on size, but it doesn't need to have this weird behaviour...

Comment: The first option worked fine! Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your property is that if the control is not the right height at the time of setting the property, the value passed to the setter is lost forever.

Therefore, in the setter, you should always assign `value` to the backing field, and check the height in the *getter*:

```
public int MyExampleProperty
{
  get => m_myExampleProperty > (this.Height / 2F) ? 1 : m_myExampleProperty;
  set
  {
    m_myExampleProperty = value;
  }
}
```

This way, you don't even need to handle the `SizeChanged` event!

Or even better, write this as two properties:

```
public int MyExampleProperty { get; set; }
public int MyExamplePropertyThatChangesWithSize => 
    MyExampleProperty > (this.Height / 2F) ? 1 : MyExampleProperty;
```

...because properties where you don't get the value that you just set is quite unexpected and can be confusing.

Comment: Only the last part to set the Size to a big value...It has just stop visual studio lol. The initial button was too big.

Comment: @PauloGuimarães Is that what happens? Okay then. I have deleted that part. It seems like the weird behaviour is not desired anyway...